# Not able to move the status bar to the bottom of the screen when the window is maximized

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, statusbar

I'm working on a WPF application. I am facing two issues.

1. Not able to set the status bar to the bottom of the window when the window is in maximized state.
2. Not able to control the containers of the WPF form via C# classes.

Code Screenshot:
[image: XAML Code]

Window Screenshot:
[image: XAML Window]

Any suggestion/help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What does the code look like currently?

Comment: The structure of the XAML is
<Window>
   <Grid>
     <DockPanel>
       <StatusBar>
       </StatusBar>
     </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

I went through a few post which suggested that the control can be accessed via the "x:Name" property. But it didnt work for me.

Comment: Hello @AnjumSKhan, I've updated my question with the screenshot of code and xaml window.

Comment: @Mohankumar Post XAML code instead of picture. And have you seen my answer.

Comment: Actually i had trouble posting the code. Your answer didnt work for me. Is it okay if i used row column definition within the grid and then set what i want and where i want?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Height` of `DockPanel`.

Set `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"` for `StatusBar` and `LastChildFill="False"`.

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="50">status bar</StatusBar>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```